# MongoDB Update Field Where Value of One Field is Greater Than Value of Another Field

Tags: mongodb

I am working with an older version of MongoDB, which is MongoDB 3.4.  And I am trying to write an Update statement, however because of the version I cannot use the $expr operator, which would allow me to compare the values of 2 fields in a document to see which one is greater and update another field if this is true.

Basically, I Need to Update Field 1, where Field 2 is blank OR Field 2 is greater than Field 3.  How do I go about doing that

Comment: Show sample documents and the expected result.